# Creating sample data set of quiz with n number of questions and set number of students using R

Tags: r, sample

I am very new to R and statistics. What I am trying to do is create some sample data sets of quizzes with n number of questions that the x number of students get correct. Using this, I would like to simulate several quizzes so that it can be determined how big of a difference is needed to notice if something is out of the norm. Searching online, I found the rnorm(n, mean, sd) function, however it only has one place to input a number. In addition to that, the numbers that come out of it are not integers.

Of all the examples I've managed to find to create sample data, none of them seem to have number of questions and number of students. Because of this, I suspect I might be going about this the wrong way...

If anyone could point me in the right direction on what keywords or search terms to use, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you want to simulate the number of students in the class, and the number of questions out of some total that each student gets correct? Can you just provide a little more info about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to simulate several sample quizzes with x number of students, so that when we do real world testing we can use our numbers from the simulations to determine how large a percentage difference between group A and group B should be considered enough to be significant.

Comment: By simulate sample quizzes, do you mean simulate the results (I.e whether or not each student gets each question correct)? And what are the groups you want to compare, students with different abilities? It sounds like you would be simulating binomial data but I still can't totally understand what you want your simulated dataset to contain

Comment: Basically we have one group of students, and we want to see if there is any significant difference if we give half of the students a quiz in a different manner than the other half. For example, half of the students sit outside while taking the quiz, while the other half stay inside. (This is just a made up example)